# Google Drive Document Time Stamp

Tags: google-drive-api

I assume that the *modifiedDate* search field is the date of modification (obviously) or upload to the drive. Is there a way to preserve the original creation date of the file on its native system? Or is there a possibility to modify this field? 
Thank you, Sean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use File.Update to set the modification date after upload.

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update

Also, File.Patch works too:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/patch

I know that I read another old thread sometime where it was discussed that it would be nice to be able to preserve the original creation date on insert, or at least to have that as an option, but this functionality does not exist yet.  (Can't find the post now...)

UPDATE:

I decided it would be nice to have a method to update the document time stamp, so here it is:

```
    public static File SetLastModified(string fileID, DateTime lastModified)
    {
        File file = DriveService.Files.Get(fileID).Fetch();
        file.ModifiedDate = lastModified.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fff'Z'");
        try
        {
            FilesResource.UpdateRequest request = DriveService.Files.Update(file, fileID);
            request.SetModifiedDate = true;
            file = request.Fetch();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw;
        }
        return file;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I have read that chapter before, but never actually noticed the 'setModifiedDate' param. Will try how it works. I have some older documents to upload and need to keep the creation date around for date range searches. sean

Comment: You can play with this methods using https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/patch APIs Explorer, which is on the bottom of the page. I always use APIs explorer in testing, to prove the concept.