# Google drive last modified date is in the future

Tags: google-drive-api

I tried getting file details of a Google account via Drive API using python.
For some files in the Google Drive account, the last modified date was way in the future,for e.g. "modifiedByMeDate": "2038-01-18T20:14:07.000Z"
In what cases would this happen? What would be a solution to this?

Thank you

Comment: As far as I know, it is possible to set the modification date programmatically as shown in this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114970/google-drive-document-time-stamp) and even use a default date to set it to a future date. Have you checked your codes within your apps if there are methods that could have set the last modified date?

Comment: I checked the code and there is no default last modified date added anywhere. Moreover, I do not see the reason to set it to a date so far in the future.

Comment: This post in the Google Product Forums https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/JGsnVUiuOm4 notes a date in the same year. I'm guessing this is a bug.

Comment: Also, someone over at SU posted a similar question also noting a date in the year 2038, and posted a series of steps to resolve the issue: http://superuser.com/questions/1171649/why-do-certain-files-keep-showing-up-at-the-top-of-the-google-drive-recent-lis