# Google Drive Api - google-apps.document - get modifiedTime

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I use Google Drive Api v3 with PHP. I have a google document - application/vnd.google-apps.document.

How can I get last modified time?

I tried:

```
$this->getClient()->files->get($id,[]);
```

And get empty all details, how to get last update date?

```
 Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile {#1362 ▼
    #collection_key: "spaces"
    +appProperties: null
    #capabilitiesType: "Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileCapabilities"
    #capabilitiesDataType: ""
    #contentHintsType: "Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileContentHints"
    #contentHintsDataType: ""
    +createdTime: null
    +description: null
    +explicitlyTrashed: null
    +fileExtension: null
    +folderColorRgb: null
    +fullFileExtension: null
    +headRevisionId: null
    +iconLink: null
    +id: "1WoKgfNSFN1sIDqbLNahTMe4Ds8rNygt2E8AkUcbO1qM"
    #imageMediaMetadataType: "Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileImageMediaMetadata"
    #imageMediaMetadataDataType: ""
    +isAppAuthorized: null
    +kind: "drive#file"
    #lastModifyingUserType: "Google_Service_Drive_User"
    #lastModifyingUserDataType: ""
    +md5Checksum: null
    +mimeType: "application/vnd.google-apps.document"
    +modifiedByMeTime: null
    +modifiedTime: null
    +name: "+ 4.4 Szkolenia żeglarskie, REJSY SZKOLENIOWE"
    +originalFilename: null
    +ownedByMe: null
    #ownersType: "Google_Service_Drive_User"
    #ownersDataType: "array"
    +parents: null
    #permissionsType: "Google_Service_Drive_Permission"
    #permissionsDataType: "array"
    +properties: null
    +quotaBytesUsed: null
    +shared: null
    +sharedWithMeTime: null
    #sharingUserType: "Google_Service_Drive_User"
    #sharingUserDataType: ""
    +size: null
    +spaces: null
    +starred: null
    +thumbnailLink: null
    +trashed: null
    +version: null
    #videoMediaMetadataType: "Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileVideoMediaMetadata"
    #videoMediaMetadataDataType: ""
    +viewedByMe: null
    +viewedByMeTime: null
    +viewersCanCopyContent: null
    +webContentLink: null
    +webViewLink: null
    +writersCanShare: null
    #internal_gapi_mappings: []
    #modelData: []
    #processed: []
  }
```

Is there another way to get this date?

Comment: As I've read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35435934/how-can-i-get-files-lastmodified-in-google-drive-api-v3), full resources are no longer returned by default in Drive API v3. Use the [fields query parameter](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration#fields) to request specific fields to be returned. You may also check on this [related thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114970/google-drive-document-time-stamp).

Answer (score 1):

You should specify what fields you need, try this

```
$response = $this->service->files->get($fileId, array(
  'fields' => 'id, name, modifiedTime',
  // uncomment the following if you are working with team drive
  //'supportsTeamDrives' => true
));
print_r($response);
```

I hope this will help

Take a look at my git repository for some helpful functions
https://github.com/sazaamout/gDrive/blob/master/gDrive.php

Take a look at the following links for more information
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters#file_fields